# Install a git repo as library into virtualenv with pip

Tags: python, git, virtualenv, pypi

I have a git repository (bitbucket private) and I want to install this repository into my virtualenv libs directory.

I try with:

pip install -e git+...... and works, but install into src, and not into lib directory.

When I execute without -e option, don't clone the repo into lib directory, create a new directory with txt files, but not my py files.

Which is the correct solution for this problem, maybe use pip in this case is an error, because is not a pip package, only one py file in a repo.

Comment: Why do you care whether it's in `src` or `lib`? Can you still `import` it?

Comment: Because if pip install the package into `src` I cannot import it from the default path